# Creating new project in Posit / Rstudio Cloud from private GitHub repository

Tags: git, github, rstudio

I am trying to open a new project in Posit Cloud from a private GitHub repository. I did the following:

- In Posit Cloud Workspace, selected "New Project" and "New Project from Git Repository" following [this guide](https://posit.cloud/learn/guide#rstudio-projects)
- Went into my [authentication settings](https://login.posit.cloud/identity/authentication) in Posit Cloud and connected my GitHub account

However, I receive this error: "Cannot access git repository" "We are unable to access a repository at that URL - make sure you entered the URL correctly and that the repository is accessible to your currently linked GitHub account."

From [this thread](https://community.rstudio.com/t/unable-to-start-new-rstudio-cloud-project-from-private-github-repository/78122) it looks like I need to edit the third party access settings on GitHub. However, I cannot figure out where or how to edit these settings. Where and how do I change these settings within GitHub?

Comment: Are you using your GitHub PAT (token) as your password?

Comment: Hello, do you mean my password for logging into Posit Cloud? Posit Cloud is not prompting me to provide another password when I try to create a project from the GitHub repo

Comment: Did you set a credential helper, as seen in "[Posit Cloud Guide / Working with Private Git Projects](https://posit.cloud/learn/guide#github-details)"?

Comment: Hello, thanks. But I can't even initialize the project in Posit Cloud, because wouldn't I have to be in the project already to enter `git config --global user.email "you@example.com"` and `git config --global user.name "Your Name"` in the console of that project?

Comment: No: global configuration can be done from any folder, not from a local repository folder.

Comment: Hello, oh I see. So I tried entering those 2 commands with my GitHub email and username in the terminal of another Posit Cloud project, then I went back and tried to start a new project from GitHub and unfortunately I am still getting the same error

Comment: Yes, those commands have nothing to do with remote authentication, only with local commit authorship. The important part, again, is the credential helper as seen in [the guide](https://posit.cloud/learn/guide#github-details): check first if you had a credential helper (`git config --global credential.helper`), which might cache the wrong credentials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I got it to work at least for me to access Git on Posit Cloud. I am waiting to hear back if my collaborators can as well.

It sounds like part of my issues were a name change problem, that when RStudio Cloud changed its name to Posit Cloud, there were some delays with GitHub adjusting to the new name.

After waiting, I was able to set it up in Posit Cloud like this:

- New Project > New Project from GitHub Repository
- copy/paste URL for repo
- Pull
- enter your username (do *not* enter anything in the password prompt yet)

Now go to GitHub:

- Settings > Developer Settings > Tokens (classic) > Generate new token > etc. > copy your new token

Now back on Posit Cloud:

- paste in your token as the password

https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/about-remote-repositories#cloning-with-https-urls